# PHP / MySQL - Select IN

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the SQL for one of my queries:

```
private static function getFixedFare($post_code_a, $post_code_b) {

    $pdo = new SQL();
    $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

    try {

        $query =   "SELECT VehicleSystemId, Fare FROM tblfixedfares
                    WHERE ShortPostCodeA = '$post_code_a'
                    AND ShortPostCodeB = '$post_code_b'
                    AND DayHalf = :day_half
                    AND VehicleSystemId IN ('Car', '6B')";

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

        $stmt->bindParam(':day_half', self::$day_half, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC|PDO::FETCH_GROUP);

        $stmt->closeCursor();

        $dbh = null;

        var_dump($result['Car']);

    }

    catch (PDOException $pe) {
        die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage(). " Query: ".$stmt->queryString);
    }

}
```

When I do a `var_dump($result['Car']);` I get the following response:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Fare"]=>
    string(3) "100"
  }
}
```

How would I go about getting the value '100'... So basically the $result for ['Car'] ['Fare'] ?

Edit ::

`var_dump($cars);` shows:

```
    array(2) {
       ["Car"]=>
       array(1) {
       [0]=>
       array(1) {
       ["Fare"]=>
       string(3) "100"
       }
     }
     ["6B"]=>
     array(1) {
     [0]=>
     array(1) {
     ["Fare"]=>
     string(3) "700"
     }
    }
```

I've tried; $result['Car']['Fare'] - but this is returning NULL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$value = $result['Car'][0]['Fare'];
```

The value for `$result['Car']` is an array, with the index of the first element being **0**; the value of that first element is an array again (one item, key **'Fare'**, value **100**).

Answer (score 1):

You'd get the value '100' exactly as you explained it, `$fare = $result['Car']['Fare']; //$fare is 100`